# Attempting to Bulk Update A Priority List - DRF

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, bulkupdate

I'm attempting to Bulk Update my entire priority list. Here's the model:

```
class OrderPriority(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order, related_name='priority_order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
```

Here's my Bulk Update Serializer and List Serializer Class:

```
class BulkPriorityUpdateListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def update(self, instances, validated_data):

        instance_hash = {index: instance for index, instance in enumerate(instances)}

        result = [
            self.child.update(instance_hash[index], attrs)
            for index, attrs in enumerate(validated_data)
        ]

        writable_fields = [
            x
            for x in self.child.Meta.fields
            if x not in self.child.Meta.read_only_fields
        ]
        
        try:
            self.child.Meta.model.objects.bulk_update(result, writable_fields)
        except IntegrityError as e:
            raise ValidationError(e)

        return result
    
    def to_representation(self, instances):

        rep_list = []
        for instance in instances:
            rep_list.append(
                dict(
                    id=instance.id,
                    order=instance.order.id,
                    priority=instance.priority,
                )
            )

        return rep_list

class BulkOrderPrioritySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderPriority
        fields = ("id", "order", "priority")
        read_only_fields = ("id",)
        list_serializer_class = BulkPriorityUpdateListSerializer
```

Here's my view along with the custom bulk update view:

```
class CustomBulkUpdateAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        def validate_ids(data, field="id", unique=True):

            if isinstance(data, list):
                id_list = [int(x[field]) for x in data]

                if unique and len(id_list) != len(set(id_list)):
                    raise ValidationError("Multiple updates to a single {} found".format(field))
                return id_list
            
            return [data]

        ids = validate_ids(request.data)

        instances = self.get_queryset(ids=ids)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            instances, data=request.data, partial=False, many=True
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        self.perform_update(serializer)

        return Response(serializer.data)

class OrderPriorityUpdateAPIView(CustomBulkUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BulkOrderPrioritySerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self, ids=None):
        return OrderPriority.objects.filter(
            id__in=ids,
        )
```

I then send a bulk PUT request with the body:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "priority": 1,
        "order": 109
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "priority": 2,
        "order": 110
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "priority": 3,
        "order": 111
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "priority": 4,
        "order": 112
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "priority": 5,
        "order": 113
    }
]
```

I then get an error:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/orders/priority-update/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 226, in put
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/order-app-backend/backend/orderapp/views.py", line 807, in update
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 748, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 618, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 666, in to_internal_value
    validated = self.child.run_validation(item)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 426, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 483, in to_internal_value
    validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 569, in run_validation
    self.run_validators(value)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 591, in run_validators
    validator(value, self)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/validators.py", line 72, in __call__
    queryset = self.exclude_current_instance(queryset, instance)
  File "/order-app-backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/validators.py", line 60, in exclude_current_instance
    return queryset.exclude(pk=instance.pk)
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'
[01/Aug/2022 14:45:19] "PUT /api/orders/priority-update/ HTTP/1.1" 500
```

I followed the Bulk Update tutorial from [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/really-fast-bulk-updates-with-django-rest-framework-43594b18bd75), and I've also used it before with no issue. Not sure what is causing the issue here. It seems the issue happens when I check .is_valid. Could I be passing the data incorrectly? Could it be that priority is a Unique field? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is in reference to https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/issues/68

Basically, I think the problem is that the child serializer is trying to run validation on the **entire** QuerySet, checking for a pk.

Your QuerySet does not contain a pk; however, **each instance** of the QuerySet does.

The solution is to overwrite the to_internal_value() method in the ListSerializer class to pass each instance one by one to the child.serializer and run the validation:

```
self.child.instance = self.instance.get(id=item['id']) if self.instance else None
self.child.initial_data = item
validated = self.child.run_validation(item)
```

Hope this helps